# Where to specify JAVA_HOME to make it visible for apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, java, environment-variables

It's CentOS 5. I created `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` file where I set and export `JAVA_HOME`. Everything works fine in terminal.

When I'm trying to get this environment variable from PHP under Apache I get the following, after using `shell_exec("env")`:

```
TERM=xterm-color
_=/bin/env
PWD=/home/...
LANG=C
SHLVL=3
```

Not even a sign of `JAVA_HOME`. Where should I declare it to make visible for apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by exporting the variables in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and then using the `PassEnv` directive to make them available to Apache e.g.

In /etc/sysconfig/httpd

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java_home
```

In `/etc/httpd/conf.d/envvars.conf` (for example)

`PassEnv JAVA_HOME`

Then restart the httpd service.